# device signature 0x000000 when burning bootloader

Tags: atmega328, bootloader, isp

I receive this message: "device signature 0x000000" when a try to burn the bootloader on a atmega328p-au (SMD) inserted on PCB
i am using arduino uno as isp i already uploaded the ArduinoISP sketch and i check "Arduino as ISP" as programmer  with "arduino nano" as board

i do not know what is the problem i tried to check the ISP wiring with the arduino uno and everything is alright
what i noticed is that when i remove the GND wire attached to ISP the pin13 of the arduino lights up when i connect it it lights off i do not know what to do
here is the full schematic [image]

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Not necessary related, but what the D4 for? it make your 7805 ground 0.6v higher than the ground.

Comment: If all the lights go out on the Arduino when you plug it in, it sounds like a short circuit...

Comment: On an unrelated note: where are all your decoupling capacitors?

Comment: @Majenko Can you explain me please why the short circuit happens and how to fix it ?

Comment: Your schematic looks ok, so it may be your PCB where the problem lies.

Comment: @Majenko you are absolutely right i fixed my bootloader problem and i was able to burn the sketch when i power 3 to 4 LEDS every thing seems to be fine but when i power on all the leds  they start blinking so quick so you are right there is a short circuit happening can you help me please ?

Comment: Take some high resolution photographs of your PCB with good lighting.

Comment: @Majenko Here are the pictures

Comment: @Majenko 
https://ibb.co/b1qh2rx
https://ibb.co/n3hthH7
https://ibb.co/42SdNYY

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Looks ok on first inspection, but you do have some quite tight clearances there. Check for shorts with a DMM

Comment: @Majenko should the tight clearances  makes a problem ?

Comment: @Majenko i will check using DMM as you told me to and i will keep you on update in the mean while please let me know if you noticed anything wrong thank you very much again

Comment: Tight clearances can cause problems with the etching.

Comment: if so can you suggest me a solution ?

Comment: @Majenko i did a test and it worked what i did is i supplied the circuit with independent 5v coming out from arduino (vcc5v & gnd) and the 12v was wired to all the LEDS only so i eliminated the role of 7805 and every thing seems to work perfect i think the D4(B5819W) seems to make the problem i do not know why this is happening  any suggestions ?

Comment: @Majenko can you please help

Comment: @Majenko you said : <<If all the lights go out on the Arduino when you plug it in, it sounds like a short circuit>> can you please explain to me why and how to fix this because it is happening :(

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I'm stuck as well.